# WCF error, service does nothing

Tags: c#, wcf, self-hosting

I am currently getting the following error when calling a WCF service:

**The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error**

However I can't understand how this could be as the method I am running doesn't actually do anything

INTERFACE:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IPrinterManager
{
    [OperationContract]
    Printer GetPrinter(int printerId);
}
```

SERVICE:

```
public class PrinterManager : IPrinterManager
{
    public PrinterManager()
    {
               }

    public Printer GetPrinter(int printerId)
    {
       return null;
    }
}
```

CLIENT:

```
 private Printer GetRequestedPrinter(int eventLocation)
    {
        ChannelFactory<IPrinterManager> channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IPrinterManager>(new BasicHttpBinding(), "http://localhost:9877/printers");
        IPrinterManager printerManager = channelFactory.CreateChannel();

        int printerId = (int) _PlcClient.ReadItem(_PlcPrinterIdWords[eventLocation], true);
        Printer printer = printerManager.GetPrinter(printerId);
        return printer;
    }
```

I can't understand why this would error?

Could anyone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: When you single-step in the debugger, can you confirm that the error occurs on the GetPrinter() call?

Comment: Yes, when single stepping in the debugger the same error occurs

Comment: I think you're return null is the problem. else try with void method  first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your includeExceptionDetailsInFaults = true

```
<serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
```

and turn on tracing

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx

this should provide you with a more clear explanation as to what is happening.